# Sequelize conditional inclusion of where clause nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this code, which has multiple `where` clause:

```
Time_Sheet_Details.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: timesheetNotesSubcon,
            required: false,
            attributes:["note","file_name", "id", "working_hrs", "timestamp", "has_screenshot", "notes_category"]
        },
        {
            model: Timesheet,
            attributes:["id","leads_id","userid"],
            where:  {leads_id: filters.leads_id}, // Client
            include:[
                {
                    model: Lead_Info, attributes:["id","fname","lname","email","hiring_coordinator_id","status"],
                    where:  {hiring_coordinator_id: {$in: filters.sc_id}}, // SC
                    include:[{
                        model: adminInfoSchema,
                        required: false,
                        attributes:["admin_id","admin_fname", "admin_lname", "admin_email", "signature_contact_nos", "signature_company"],      
                    }]

                },
                {
                    model:Personal_Info,attributes:["userid","fname","lname","email"],
                    where: {userid: filters.subcon_id}, // Subcon
                }
            ]
        }],
    where: { 
        reference_date: filters.reference_date
    },
    order:[
        ["id","DESC"]
    ],
    offset:((page-1)*limit),
    limit : limit,
    subQuery:false

}).then(function(foundObject){
    willFulfillDeferred.resolve(foundObject);
});
```

The `where` clause is the one with the comment Client, SC and Subcon. However, what is the best approach if those `where` clause is optional? I am using that for search filter. So if `filters.leads_id` is `null` then the `where:  {leads_id: filters.leads_id}, // Client`  should not be included in the query. Same with the others. The only solution I can think of is repeat those code blocks for each scenario of not null parameters but that's to repetitive and not practical.

Any other approach or solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think as a first step, you should define your respective where clauses, conditionally upon wether or not each specific search criteria is set:

```
const clientWhere = filters.leads_id ? {leads_id: filters.leads_id} : {}
const scWhere = filters.sc_id ? {hiring_coordinator_id: {$in: filters.sc_id}} : {}
const subconWhere = filters.subcon_id ? {userid: filters.subcon_id} : {}
```

So at this point if a search option isn't set, there'll just be an empty object as the where clause.

Next, use those pre-defined where clause objects in your query:

```
Time_Sheet_Details.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: timesheetNotesSubcon,
            required: false,
            attributes:["note","file_name", "id", "working_hrs", "timestamp", "has_screenshot", "notes_category"]
        },
        {
            model: Timesheet,
            attributes:["id","leads_id","userid"],
            where: clientWhere, // Client
            include:[
                {
                    model: Lead_Info, attributes:["id","fname","lname","email","hiring_coordinator_id","status"],
                    where: scWhere, // SC
                    include:[{
                        model: adminInfoSchema,
                        required: false,
                        attributes:["admin_id","admin_fname", "admin_lname", "admin_email", "signature_contact_nos", "signature_company"],      
                    }]

                },
                {
                    model:Personal_Info,attributes:["userid","fname","lname","email"],
                    where: subconWhere, // Subcon
                }
            ]
        }],
    where: { 
        reference_date: filters.reference_date
    },
    order:[
        ["id","DESC"]
    ],
    offset:((page-1)*limit),
    limit : limit,
    subQuery:false

}).then(function(foundObject){
    willFulfillDeferred.resolve(foundObject);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For some reason my code did not work with an empty object {}, I had to use undefined such as *const clientWhere = filters.leads_id ? {leads_id: filters.leads_id} : undefined*